# Equal spacing between controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to place image and text under image as below. The height of the rows have to be equally divided. How can this work if I want images to size accordingly?

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication5;component/led.green.off.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            </Image>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Turret Power" ></TextBlock>

            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication5;component/toggle.sheath.DOWN.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            </Image>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="Off" ></TextBlock>

            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication5;component/toggle.sheath.DOWN.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            </Image>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Text="Off" ></TextBlock>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication5;component/toggle.sheath.DOWN.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            </Image>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Text="Off" ></TextBlock>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication5;component/toggle.sheath.DOWN.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            </Image>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" Text="Off" ></TextBlock>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication5;component/toggle.sheath.DOWN.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            </Image>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11" Text="Off" ></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

If I do the above, the images are big and go over the window

Comment: I'm gonna need a screenshot here... I tested it and have no problem, my images are correctly resized to fit their cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're missing 2 `<RowDefinition>` in `<Grid.RowDefinitions>` (according to your usages of `Grid.Row`)
- You don't have to put a weight in your row/column definitions if they're all the same, and you don't even have to set `Height` if the value is `*`, since this is the default (you can remove `Height="10*"` from each `<RowDefinition>`)
- Maybe you'll want to have some column definitions set with `Width="Auto"`, but I'll leave that to you.